# SUDO Password Suddenly Stopped

Tags: password, root

So I am plugging along quite happily on my new Linux (Ubuntu) box when suddenly my root password has ceased to work.  I get one of two errors:

- "Your authentication was unsuccessful. Please try again." or
- "___ is not in the sudoers file.'

This literally happened while I was using the computer. One minute it works fine, the next it doesn't.  I can't edit the `/usr/sbin/visudo` file because sudo won't accept my password.

There has only ever been one user account on this computer and I have never changed a password. What can i do to fix it?

Comment: What is the output of terminal command `id -Gn`?

Comment: the only group listed is my username.

Comment: I am also trying to boot into recovery mode, but I don't get the normal menu, just a GRUB line.  Sigh